# ObjC [NSMachPort port] into Swift translation

Tags: swift

I can't translate this Objective-C code into Swift

```
NSRunLoop *runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runloop addPort:[NSMachPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

The problem is about `[NSMachPort port]` . How it looks in Swift?

This code as shown as incorrect:

```
let runloop:NSRunLoop = NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop()
            runloop.addPort(NSMachPort.port, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
```

Neither `NSMachPort.port`  or `NSMachPort.port()` are correct.

Does `NSPort()` the same as `[NSMachPort port]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSMachPort` is a subclass of `NSPort` rather than the latter being an improved name, so `NSPort()` will not construct an `NSMachPort`.

`NSMachPort()` is the equivalent of `[NSMachPort port]`.